# Bootstrap column wrap down based on title on mobile view

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using multiple bootstrap column inside the single class. Now I achieved column wrap down when has title using `clear:both`. But the only problem in mobile view can't align the column left when item has no title. Here my sample code and also I have attached screen for your reference.

[my web link](http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product/view/Homogeneous)
[screenshot follow](https://ibb.co/mxGcXx)

```
<div class="itemat htile1 col-xs-12">
<div class="secn-frst1">
    <h4 class="tileh4 a">600mm x 600mm</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Written jquery below

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
        //alert();  
        $(".posts.Homogeneous div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn)").parent().css("clear", "both");
        $(".posts.Porcelain div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn)").parent().css("clear", "both");
        $(".posts.Ceramic div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn)").parent().css("clear", "both");

        $(".posts.Homogeneous .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn)").parent().css("clear", "both");
        $(".posts.Porcelain .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn)").parent().css("clear", "both");
        $(".posts.Ceramic .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn)").parent().css("clear", "both");

//div has no title cleat none
    $(".posts.Homogeneous div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");    
    $(".posts.Porcelain div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");
    $(".posts.Ceramic div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");

    } else {
        $(".posts.Homogeneous div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn),.posts.Homogeneous div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");
        $(".posts.Porcelain div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn),.posts.Porcelain div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");
        $(".posts.Ceramic div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn),.posts.Ceramic div[class*='htile'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");

        $(".posts.Homogeneous .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn),.posts.Homogeneous .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");
        $(".posts.Porcelain .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn),.posts.Porcelain .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");
        $(".posts.Ceramic .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.versn),.posts.Ceramic .htile1 div[class*='secn-frst'] .col-sm-3 .tileh4:has(.vhide)").parent().css("clear", "none");
    }
});

//remove classname row in mobile
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
        var cnt = $(".posts.Homogeneous .htile1 .row").contents();
        $(".posts.Homogeneous .htile1 .row").replaceWith(cnt);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to modify the inline style clear : both in width <=767. I think it will work...

Comment: No sarvan. Inline style applied using above jquery. the div repeated using php code.

Comment: Ok. I think you can modify that. Otherwise use this.
// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();
 
// Returns width of HTML document
$( document ).width();

Comment: Get the width and add some jquery for that particular width

Comment: Can't understand what you saying. You did't understand my prob check the screenshot. and write an answer if possible.

Comment: You can not expect the grid to work properly, if you violate its basic structure to begin with. Columns need to be children of a row.

Comment: I need to do without row on mobile.

Comment: Why you need to do without row on mobile? Any reason?

Comment: @SaurabhLP Becz I need all column comes from left to right without any gap. And also the column wrap to left side if its has title

Comment: Check the answer by me.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you like to do. Let me know that `row` class in compulsory if you add `col-....` for developing the grid layout because other than `padding` it wraps `col-..` divs to the `row` class. What you can do is add a `div` as a child of `col-...` and add `margin` in negative value.

Following is the representation you could follow.

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
.mgn-rt-15 { margin-right:-15px; }
.mgn-lt-15 { margin-left:-15px; }
.green-box,
.blue-box { height:150px; }
.green-box { background-color:green; }
.blue-box { background-color:blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="mgn-rt-15">
         <div class="green-box"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="mgn-lt-15">
         <div class="blue-box"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry.  you're not understand my question properly.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't saw your screenshot added, you want the 3rd item to be in left rather than right?